# Error setting primary key in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am having trouble in setting primary key for a datatable with existing column. I am getting this exception

> These columns don't currently have unique values.

The code I am using for the same is like,

```
dtTemp.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtTemp.Columns("mycolumn")}
```

where `mycolumn` is an existing column in datatable `dtTemp` with rows like

```
501,502,503,...901,902,903
```

(doesn't have unique values)

Note:

The same code with same random values in datatable column works well in one of the similar projects. Any directions would be helpful.

Comment: Well, the error really says it all - if your column contains **duplicate values**, then you just cannot use it as a primary key - period. Uniqueness is one of the cornerstones of what a primary key is - if you have duplicates - you need to get rid of them!

Comment: at first i didnt find any duplicate..anyway let me double check it.

Comment: thanks `marc_s`..i have found one duplicate entry after thorough checking.that was the culprit.now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `EnforceConstraints` property to `False`

example -

```
dtTemp.EnforceConstraints = False
dtTemp.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtTemp.Columns("mycolumn")}
```